# Is is legal to pay an extra fee for moving out early of an apartment in Germany?

Tags: germany, rental

I live in an apartment in Germany. The whole building belongs to a private company.

My rental contract ends at the end of a month. I asked to move out at the middle of the month (still paying for the whole month).
They want to charge me an extra 50€ for this "special appointment", and I have to pay in cash.

Is it a common practice in Germany? Is it even legal?

Comment: Just checking to clarify: That special appointment is for handing over the apartment and keys, right?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft yes, exactly.

Comment: Since you are paying until the end of the month anyway why don't you handover the apartment on the designated date ?

Comment: @Rsf For convenience. It is mandatory to rent until the end of a month (you cannot stop the contract in the middle of a month for instance), but I need to leave before. Coming back to Germany afterward just to do the handover would be more expensive than this 50€.

Comment: I strongly suspect that it is illegal. I don’t have any laws or court rulings to back that suspicion, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a problem that solely affects expats, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps they are paying someone to go out of their way to collect those keys from you?

Comment: @MarkMayo According to [the upvoted and accepted answer on this meta question](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/42/6), problems that equally accept to locals are not necessarily off-topic.

Comment: @gerrit indeed, but then this isn't even travel related. It's apartment related.